# How to check previous inputs in hangman game

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript and i have project in which I have to make a hangman game. I have already built a function that replace `_` with correct answers.
If password is "MOM":

if you guess `M` then you have `M _ M`,

if you guess `O` then you have `_ O _`,

if you guess `L` then you have `_ _ _`.

But I don't know how to make tat user cannot guess the same character the twice.
here is my Code:

```
function check(){
    let char = document.querySelector("character").value;
    for(let i = 0; i<password.length;i++){
      if(char == password[i]){
        passwordToGuess=passwordToGuess.replaceChar(i,char);
        alreadyUsed.pop(char);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: create an array with the characters you allow. Remove the character from the array when it is guessed?
Or the otherway around. Push the guessed letters to a new array and check if the guessed letter exists there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array 'guesses' and before executing the loop check if the char is inside 'guesses':

```
guesses.includes(char) // returns true or false
```

at the end of the loop .push the guess to guesses